# Problem with multipart data with NodeJS and Retrofit

Tags: javascript, java, android, node.js, retrofit

I have this in my android app with retrofit.

```java
@Multipart
@POST("myEndpoint")
Call<...> myMethod(@Header("Authorization") String auth, @Part("part") MyHugeObj hugeObj);
```

What i want is to send a very huge object to my NodeJS backend, that will be converted to a also huge json string. Just for info, my huge object contains a image (Base64 encoded) between 300KB and 5MB aprox.

What i have in my NodeJS is to parsing is:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '300kb'}));
```

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer();

const myController = require('myPath');

router.post('/myEndpoint', upload.none(), (req, res, next) => myController.doWhatever(req, res, next));
```

Actually, everything works just fine, my huge json reaches my backend and i do what i have to do with the image and the rest of the info, and a success response reaches my android app. And that is it, everything works. The problem is that pops this error in my NodeJS console:

```
Error: request entity too large
    at readStream (...)
    at getRawBody (...)
    at read (...)
    at rawParser (...)
    at trim_prefix (...)
    at Function.process_params (...)
    at next (...)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (...)
    at trim_prefix (...)
    at Function.process_params (...)
    at next (...)
    at serveStatic (...)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (...)
    at trim_prefix (...)
    at Function.process_params (...)
    at Immediate.next (...)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (...)
    at runCallback (...)
```

The question is: **Why is this happening?** I don`t even have a raw parser defined, i just have json and urlEncoded.

EDIT 1:
It has something to do with the response. If i do not send a success or error response, this error does not pops up.